# Juniper SRX: Where do I look to see IKE debug messages?

Tags: vpn, juniper, juniper-srx, ike

Going through a JSEC book I noticed the following slide explains that there are 6 ike phase 1 messages that take place for a tunnel to establish.

[image: ike messages]

I am looking in the `kmd` log and `traceoptions` data but I do not see any information relating to the IKE messages pictured in those logs. Perhaps I am looking at it wrong? If my SRX is hanging up on one of those messages where would I look to determine that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Juniper KB explaining how to locate / interpret information in the  Kmd log : [How do I Find the VPN Entry in the Kmd Log on a J-Series or SRX-Series device?](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB10097&smlogin=true)

although for releases prior to 12 the following kmd log issues below are also relevant for the higher end firewalls.
[[SRX High End] request security ike debug-enable does not print any useful kmd debug output](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB25297)

**its quite key which SRX and what software version you're using really.**

for reference only really , I use this method to troubleshoot a singe vpn tunnel without having to actually make any changes / commits

> user@srx>request security ike debug-enable local  remote  level
>
> user@srx>show log /var/log/kmd
>
> user@srx>request security ike debug-disable

Explained in detail here:
KB [[SRX] How can I enable IKE traceoptions for only specific security associations](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB19943)